# curl_multi_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in

Tags: php, opencart, php-curl

I recently updated PHP 7.2 (from 5.x), and one of my Opencart plugins started acting weird. I think this happens when curl tries to connect to a 404 link. In the log, I see:

> curl_multi_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle
> resource in

I think it is an infinity loop because it doesn't stop itself. The code is the following:

```php
public function uploadMultipleImages($images, $importer, &$parent)
{
    set_error_handler('error_handler_for_export', E_ALL);
    register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_shutdown_handler_for_export');
    if (count($images) == 0)
        return true;
    //ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    try {
        $img = array();
        $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'data/' . str_replace('../', '', $importer), '/');

        if (!is_dir($directory))
            if (!mkdir($directory, 0777, true))
                die('Failed to create folders...');

        $pack = 30;

        $chs = array();
        $cmh = curl_multi_init();

        if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
            $parent->log->write('PHP xml Image: Images to download: ' . count($images));
        }

        for ($t = 0; $t < $pack && $t < count($images); $t++) {

            $chs[$t] = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, $images[$t]['image']);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
            curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
            if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Added to queue image 51: ' . $images[$t]['image'] . ' CNT: ' . count($chs));
            }
        }

        do {

            while (($execrun = curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) ;
            if ($execrun != CURLM_OK)
                break;
            //usleep(200000); 
            // Block for data in / output; error handling is done by curl_multi_exec
            curl_multi_select($cmh);

            // a request was just completed -- find out which one
            while ($done = curl_multi_info_read($cmh)) {

                $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
                if ($info['http_code'] > 199 && $info['http_code'] < 300) {

                    $file = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);


                    // handle the done request
                    if ($file != null && $file != '' && !empty($file) && $file != 'null') {
                        $parts = parse_url($info['url']);
                        $filename = basename($parts['path']);
                        $path_to_file = $directory . '/' . $filename;

                        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                            $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Image extension: ' . $ext);
                        }
                        $ok = TRUE;
                        if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'gif') {
                            $path_to_file = $directory . '/' . $this->clean_filename($filename);
                            $theFileName = $this->clean_filename($filename);
                        } else {
                            $path_to_file = $directory . '/' . $this->clean_filename($filename . $parts['query']);
                            $theFileName = $this->clean_filename($filename . $parts['query']) . ".jpg";

                            switch ($info['content_type']) {
                                case 'image/jpeg':
                                    $path_to_file = $path_to_file . '.jpg';
                                    $theFileName = $theFileName . '.jpg';
                                    $ok = TRUE;
                                    break;
                                case 'image/gif':
                                    $path_to_file = $path_to_file . '.gif';
                                    $theFileName = $theFileName . '.gif';
                                    $ok = TRUE;
                                    break;
                                case 'image/png':
                                    $path_to_file = $path_to_file . '.png';
                                    $theFileName = $theFileName . '.png';
                                    $ok = TRUE;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    $ok = FALSE;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                            $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Image type: ' . $info['content_type']);
                        }

                        if ($ok === TRUE)
                            if (file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file) > 0) {
                                if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                                    $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Image saved image: ' . $info['url']);
                                }
                                $parent->nr_images_imported++;
                            }
                    }
                    unset($file);
                } else {
                    // request failed.  add error handling.
                    if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                        $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Failed downloading image: ' . $info['url']);
                    }
                }

                // start a new request (it's important to do this before removing the old one)
                if ($t + 1 < count($images)) {
                    $t++;
                    $chs[$t] = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, $images[$t]['image']);
                    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
                    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
                    curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
                    if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                        $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Added to queue image: 147' . $images[$t]['image'] . ' CNT: ' . count($chs));
                    }
                }

                // remove the curl handle that just completed
                curl_close($done['handle']);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $done['handle']);
                if (($key = array_search($done['handle'], $chs)) !== false) {
                    unset($chs[$key]);
                }
                unset($done);
                clearstatcache();
                if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                    $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Removed from queue image 160: ' . $info['url'] . ' CNT: ' . count($chs));
                }
                if ($t % 50 == 0) {
                    $parent->db->query("SELECT 1");
                    if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                        $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: PING - MYSQL! 165 ');
                    }
                }

            }

        } while ($running);

        if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
            $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Before images m_CURL_CLOSE !');
        }

        curl_multi_close($cmh);
        //PING
        $parent->db->query("SELECT 1");

        return TRUE;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errstr = $e->getMessage();
        $errline = $e->getLine();
        $errfile = $e->getFile();
        $errno = $e->getCode();
        $parent->session->data['export_error'] = array('errstr' => $errstr, 'errno' => $errno, 'errfile' => $errfile, 'errline' => $errline);
        if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
            $parent->log->write('PHP ' . get_class($e) . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl\_multi\_exec(): is not a valid cURL handle resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346961/curl-multi-exec-is-not-a-valid-curl-handle-resource)

Comment: I saw this topic before, but not helped much.

Comment: Have you looked into the return values of `curl_multi_add_handle` to make sure they are all zero? Also, `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` was [deprecated in 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19491013/231316) but I don't know if that would affect you.

Comment: If you need help it's better to provide your version of OpenCart and name of the module

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to make some actions to make sure everything is ok, first:

**(1)** - Make sure the provided URLs of images for the cUrl is a valid (well-formatted) URL by replacing this:

```
curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, $images[$t]['image']);
```

For this (add urlencode):

```
curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($images[$t]['image']));
```

To prevent the possible error of the URL not being well formatted, more info here: https://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/after-curl-site-is-slow/

**(2)** - Then, according to the official manual ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php)), you should call:

`curl_multi_init()` after `curl_init()`

This way, you should move the:

```
$cmh = curl_multi_init();
```

After the `for` element, like:

```
        for ($t = 0; $t < $pack && $t < count($images) ; $t++)
        {

            $chs[$t] = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, $images[$t]['image']);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
            curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);

            curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);    // <-- DELETE THIS LINE

            if ($parent->config->get('config_error_log')) {
                $parent->log->write('PHP Importer Images: Added to queue image 51: ' . $images[$t]['image'] . ' CNT: '. count($chs));
            }
        }

        //AND MOVE IT HERE (remember deleting the first $cmh = curl_multi_init();
        $cmh = curl_multi_init();
        for ($t = 0; $t < $pack && $t < count($images) ; $t++) {
           curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
        }

        do {
           ...
```

And remember deleting the first `$cmh = curl_multi_init();`.
You could check more in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080230/php-curl-warning-during-curl-multi-add-handle).

And finally, if you have an infinite loop, check the condition/state of the `do{ ... } while()` and `while()` calls, like `$running` to assure the loop finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in practice disables the redirect limit in cURL. Due to this, if the called page were to send you a specific type of redirect (as some 404 pages are wont to do), you might find yourself in an endless loop.

You can easily check this by having each curl request print its target URL.

To solve the problem, not ideal, and it could break some other code, but... if you can't check explicitly the redirect status from the curl handle (which is the right way to go), then try setting the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` options to 0.